# How to handle the redundancy of AppServer in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, appserver-index-server

am going to have a  APPSERVER in my  SP 2013 farm environment. I would be having 2 WFEs and 1  index server and 2  sql servers with mirroring configured in the SP FARM.

how to handle the redundancy of AppServer in SP 2013 ?
In case of a hardware failure of  APPSERVER in this farm how to overcome this situation?

I have gone through the below link
[search-crawl-index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727118(v=office.15).aspx#BKMK_HWMiniIndex)
 for search related things. But i am not able to see anything related to redundancy. Incase of failure of APPSERVER, how the search will be functional ? in case, wfe, it will be decided by NLB,it will failover and switch to 2nd WFE. but what will happen if APPSERVER  fails?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add two app servers, or convert the index server to an app server and add one  more to create a fault-tolerant farm.

> **Smallest fault-tolerant farm utilizing virtualization** All farm server roles virtualized and distributed across two or four host
>   servers  to provide fault tolerance using the minimum number of
>   servers.
>
> [image]

See: [*Traditional Topologies for SharePoint 2013* in the article *Technical diagrams for SharePoint 2013*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx)